# Difference between maximum and second maximum from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame I wanted the difference between the maximum and second maximum from the DataFrame as a new column appended to the DataFrame as output.

The data frame looks like this for example (this is quite a huge DataFrame):

```
 gene_id    Time_1  Time_2  Time_3
a   0.01489251  8.00246 8.164309
b   6.67943235  0.8832114   1.048761
```

So far I tried the following but it's just taking the headers,

```
largest = max(df)
second_largest = max(item for item in df if item < largest)
```

and returning the header value alone.

Comment: Your question is unclear, max in terms of the whole df? column? row?

Comment: You are iterating over the column names so what else do you expect?

Comment: The maximum is in terms of  rows, for the whole df. ie for first row max is 8.164309 and second max is 8.00246 and I want the difference between the max and second max as new column appended to the df

Comment: There's a function `nlargest()` in module `heapq` which finds the *n* largest values of a collection; with *n* = 2 this might speed up things for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a func which takes the values, sorts them, slices the top 2 values (`[:2]`) then calculates the difference and returns the second value (as the first value is `NaN`). You `apply` this and pass arg `axis=1` to apply row-wise:

```
In [195]:
def func(x):
    return -x.sort(inplace=False, ascending=False)[:2].diff()[1]

df['diff'] = df.loc[:,'Time_1':].apply(func, axis=1)
df

Out[195]:
  gene_id    Time_1    Time_2    Time_3      diff
0       a  0.014893  8.002460  8.164309  0.161849
1       b  6.679432  0.883211  1.048761  5.630671
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but the difference is between MAX-Second MAX so it is not a negative value..

Comment: You can just change the sign to negative `-` in the return, see update

Comment: Thanks perfect ..!!! With " " instead of '' for df['diff'] = df.loc[:,"Time_1":].apply(func, axis=1)

Comment: This can go wrong depending on the column names. It's safer to use `.diff().iloc[1]`. Also, this is pretty inefficient as it uses sort and apply, neither of which are necessary. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
# Load data
data = {'a': [0.01489251, 8.00246, 8.164309], 'b': [6.67943235, 0.8832114, 1.048761]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, 'index')
```

The trick is to do a linear sort of the values and keep the top-2 using [numpy.argpartition](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html).
You do the difference of the 2 maximum values in absolute value. The function is applied row-wise.

```
def f(x):
    ind = np.argpartition(x.values, -2)[-2:]
    return np.abs(x.iloc[ind[0]] - x.iloc[ind[1]])

df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: Assuming you can afford the higher memory overhead, `np.partition(df, kth=-2, axis=1)[:, -2:].ptp(axis=1)` could be much quicker (it's fully vectorized, has only one call to `partition`, has fewer indexing operations and uses `ptp()` to calculate the absolute value of the difference).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an elegant solution that doesn't involve sorting or defining any functions. It's also fully vectorized as it avoid use of the `apply` method.

```
maxes = df.max(axis=1)
less_than_max = df.where(df.lt(maxes, axis='rows'))
seconds = less_than_max.max(axis=1)
df['diff'] = maxes - seconds
```